# div with position fixed appears to move to an incorrect location when the browser goes fullscreen on mobile

Tags: css-position, viewport, android-fullscreen

The answer found on
[Viewport height problem when browser goes fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56777751/viewport-height-problem-when-browser-goes-fullscreen)
does NOT solve this issue.

No problems ever seen on desktop.
But both on tablet and on phone, although more than half of the time everything is displayed correctly, sometimes -unpredictably- the problematic process starts and goes as follows; first let's say we have a page like this,

[image: step one]

and then when the "go fullscreen" button is tapped the address bar is removed and I see this for an instant,

[image: step two]

and then the div just stays above where it is supposed to be sitting,

[image: step three]

At this stage touching the screen or making a random swipe gesture corrects the position of the div. The impression is like some kind of REDRAW function is triggered by that.

[image: step four]

It looks like the order of events within the browser, when switching to fullscreen, is not always the same and when that final REDRAW gets late for a few milliseconds this problem occurs.
If I knew a method to force the browser to redraw everything in the DOM maybe I could fix this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac help?

Answer (score 1):

As an improvised solution I have tried giving the div an unnoticable nudge hoping that it would be something like a forced screen refresh,

```
window.addEventListener("resize", myDivShakingFunction);
function myDivShakingFunction()
{
  setTimeout(function()
  { document.getElementById("theIdOfTheDivWithThisProblem").style.bottom = "-1px";  },100);

  // the durations may be adjusted for fine tuning through trial and error if necessary

  setTimeout(function()
  { document.getElementById("theIdOfTheDivWithThisProblem").style.bottom = "0px";  },200);
}
```

It seems to be working! Though I haven't tried it enough many times to be 100% certain.